# TYPO3 extbase: get some from FrontendUserGroupRepository

Tags: repository, typo3, extbase

In a class file I can get all records from another repository that is not mine

```
$allUsergroups = $this->feGroupRepository->findAll();
```

How to make custom function to acomplish something like this on such a repository in the most correct way?

```
// magic default function that takes a uid list (or array) as argument
$someUsergroups = $this->feGroupRepository->findSomeByUidList('2,4,6,8');
```

Or can I extent an existing repository with my own custom functions, in this case based on `$query->in(list)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend Repository of a foreign TYPO3 extbase extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926089/extend-repository-of-a-foreign-typo3-extbase-extension)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926089/extend-repository-of-a-foreign-typo3-extbase-extension

Comment: extBase https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html and old query method https://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Developers_Guide#Query_execution both working in latest version. it'll helps to you for your own custom query, I hope so ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own method in your `extensionRepository.php` class

you can use :

```
in($propertyName, $operand)
```

or

```
contains($propertyName, $operand)
```

> Contrarily, the methods in() and contains() accept multi-value data types as arguments (e.g. Array, ObjectStorage).

take a look how some other extension are doing stuff. (like the tx_news extension)

or read some docs here :
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html

Comment: and I need to read the questions better. in short, yes you can use $query->in()

Comment: Thank you so much. But my problem is that it is not "my" repository, but "another". Could be a sysext repository like FrontendUserGroupRepository that I would like to extend.

Comment: then 'extend' that class ;)  ->  class peace Extends world

Comment: ok. Sounds like I lack some basic OOP :-) But it makes sense. Thanks, I know what to look for now..

Comment: You don't need to extend the repository - just do something like this: `$query = $this->feGroupRepository->createQuery(); $query->matching($query->in([2,3,4,5,6])); $feGroups = $query->execute();`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can extend another class in TYPO3 without any need to change any other code. It´s called `Dependency Injection` in ExtBase context.

First, create a new repository class `your_ext/Classes/Domain/Repository/FrontendUserRepository.php` and add below content to it:

```php
<?php
namespace Tillebeck\YourExt\Domain\Repository;

class FrontendUserRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository {
    /**
     * @param array $uidList
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface
     */
    public function findByUidList(Array $uidList)
    {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        //$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);
        $query->matching(
            $query->in('uid', $uidList)
        );
        return $query->execute();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getRepositoryClassName()
    {
        return get_parent_class($this);
    }
}
```

Here we have implemented your method `findByUidList` with the required argument `$uidList` which needs to be an array.

Because repositories resolve their model names by their own class name, we need to change the method `getRepositoryClassName` to return the parent class name, in this case `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository`.

But this alone won't work. We need to tell ExtBase that every time we inject or initialize a `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository`, either by PHPDocBlock annotation `@inject` or by the `objectManager->get`, then we really want to initialize our new repository. This is done in TypoScript.

```
config.tx_extbase.objects {
    TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository {
        className = Tillebeck\YourExt\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository
    }
}
```

You can also restrict your change to your own extension alone by replacing `config.tx_extbase` with `plugin.tx_yourext`.

Last step: clear ALL cache, and possibly delete all files in typo3temp directory.

Now in your controller (or other class) you can run below code.

```php
$uidList = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::trimExplode(',', '2,4,6,8', true);
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump(
    $this->frontendUserRepository->findByUidList($uidList)
);
```

I have tested above solution in TYPO3 7.6 and it works. `Dependency Injection` has existed since version 6.1.

This is by my definition the must correct way, as you asked, to implement this feature in your own TYPO3 extension.